# How to extend Non-UML stereotypes in Enterprise Architect V8.0?

Tags: enterprise-architect

I'm defining a new EA profile that extends the types introduced in BPMN profile. So it will be an extension for another extension. It seems that the newer versions of Enterprise Architect provide facilities for this purpose. However my EA version is 8.0 and does not include utilities as "MDG Profile Helper".

Technically the challenge is where I have to apply the "Metaclass" to the Non-UML types (e.g. BPMN Activity). 
How is possible to provide the reference for such type?
I tried the namespace approach (BPMN1.1::Activity) and was not valid in "Profile" definition but worked well in "Toolbox" creation where the reference is given as "attribute".

Comment: It's been a while since I used EA 8, but I think you may be out of luck. Instead you may need to resort to multiple stereotypes. BPMN1.1::Activity extends UML::Activity, so create your own stereotype that extends UML::Activity and apply both stereotypes to your element.

Comment: Thanks Chimp. Is there a way to import a profile in XML format into EA project how that I can modify it (reverse engineering)? Or should the XML content of the original profile be copied manually into the new designed profile?

Comment: Or let me ask my question like this: How is it possible to apply the BPMN Activity stereotype to a MetaClass?